# How to count the number of occurrences of a nested dictionary key?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a nested dictionary:

```
d = {'key': 1, 'lock':{'key': 3, 'lock': {'key': 7, 'lock': None}}}
```

and I am hoping to simply get the number of times 'key' occurs. So in this example, the output would be:

```
3
```

because 'key' appears 3 times. I know this is pretty straight forward but I'm a bit foggy on how to do this with dictionaries. **I would prefer to not use any libraries if possible.**

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a function that recursively counts the given key:

```
def count(d, k):
    c = int(k in d)
    for v in d.values():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            c += count(v, k)
    return c
```

or to write the above in a more concise way:

```
def count(d, k):
    return (k in d) + sum(count(v, k) for v in d.values() if isinstance(v, dict))
```

so that `count(d, 'key')` returns: `3`

Comment: Thanks for the help! Just one thing though, no matter what I put in for an argument for "k", it returns 2

Comment: Glad to be of help. How are you calling it? Please check the demo: https://repl.it/repls/WateryFeistyLegacy

Comment: I'm calling it like this: print(count(d, "key")) . It works for everything else two or above but for example I put  put   print(count(d,'ooooo')) and I still got 2 @blhsing

Comment: Oops that was a bug indeed. Just fixed it. Please try again.